# use pandoc to embed images into a docx file that are in a HTML

Tags: pandoc

Is it possible to embed images into a docx file that are embedded in a HTML file?

I am trying and it's not working for me, and perhaps I am not adding some extra parameter when I am running pandoc.

pandoc -f html -t docx -o testdoc.docx image.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: I just discovered pandoc because of your SO entry. Thank you very much, it's saving me hours.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this by executing the following command:

```
pandoc -s file_name.html -o file_name.docx;
```

There are actually 2 important points that you need to consider:

1. The quality of the output file is pretty much related to how pandoc interpret your HTML file, so that if the source was pretty complex then you wouldn't really expect a pretty good quality output, for instance the `<hr/>` tag is not recognized by pandoc, while the `<p>` tag is.
2. The path of the image is not an HTTP path but instead it is a full desk path, meaning:

This is NO good:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/img.jpg" />
```

And This is what pandoc can really read:

```
<img src="/var/www/example.com/images/img.jpg" />
```

HTH

Comment: I just discovered pandoc because of your SO entry. Thank you very much, it's saving me hours.