# Pandoc HTML to DOCX images load locally but not on server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, docker, pandoc

I am currently using Rails 4.2 and pandoc-ruby to convert my HTML documents to DOCX for user download. Unfortunately, the docx created by the server doesn't display images. Locally it does.

**Edit**: I'm running pandoc 1.19 locally (on Mac). I got docker to install the new version of pandoc without issue. Running `pandoc -v` or `pandoc --version` gives me the following output from docker:

```
root@3dd9b57878f1:~# pandoc -v
pandoc 1.19.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4
```

Here's what I get on my mac (installed by brew):

```
~ ❯❯❯ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.19
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, highlighting-kate 0.6.3
```

My rails app creates a preview page that contains images pulled down from S3, so the img src is the standard s3 URL, e.g. "https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/xyz/image.jpg?1234567890"

On my machine, when I have pandoc-ruby convert the page to docx, the images all get pulled down without issue, and the docx looks just like the preview page. The image isn't stored in the rails directory -- only through s3. On docker, that isn't the case. It instead references the ID of my image.  According to the generated XML, the docker one doesn't even have the same XML:

locally:

```
<w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Compact" /></w:pPr><w:r><w:drawing><wp:inline><wp:extent cx="3048000" cy="2286000" />
<wp:effectExtent b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0" /><wp:docPr descr="4" title="" id="1" name="Picture" />
<a:graphic><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
<pic:pic>
<pic:nvPicPr>
<pic:cNvPr descr="http://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/development/assets/xyz/2345585/4.jpg?123456789" id="0 ...
```

the docker version:

```
<w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Image</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Compact" /></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">475</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:sectPr /></w:body></w:document>
```

(the 475 is the id of the image)

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955656/generating-a-docx-file-using-pandoc-images-missing-due-to-multiple-requests?rq=1) as well as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527151/use-pandoc-to-embed-images-into-a-docx-file-that-are-in-a-html) it could be that the URLs aren't pointing to images on disk.  And that seemed to be an issue with an older version of Pandoc. It doesn't explain why it works locally, since the XML is using the URL.

Could it be that the docker container is still running the 1.16 version despite me manually installing 1.19.x?

Comment: not too familiar with docker, but why not try `pandoc -v`?

Comment: @mb21 If I'm not mistaken, isn't `--version` the same thing as `-v` ? In any case, it's the same value as before: 1.19.2.1, to be precise. Do the other version types matter?  This is the next line: `Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4`

Comment: I updated my question to include the 2 `pandoc -v` outputs. Looks like the difference is skylighting (ubuntu) vs highlighting-kate (mac). Could that be the reason, potentially? Or are they simply different because it's different OSes?

Comment: 1.19.2.1 has lots of changes from 1.19.0... try updating to the newest version and see whether the problem persists... (among the changes is the update to the new syntax-highlighting lib skylighting which shouldn't concern you)

Comment: @mb21 ah sorry for the confusion - locally everything works and that was running 1.19.0. It still works with 1.19.2.1 (local == mac).  the server (ubuntu/docker) is running 1.19.2.1 but is not outputting the images.  both are using s3 urls. At this point the only difference is now ubuntu+docker vs mac. Or maybe a concurrency issue?

Comment: hm... `http://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/development/assets/xyz/2345585/4.jpg?123456789` gives me an `access denied`

Comment: @mb21  the original URL references internal things so I replaced the xyz and 123456789 parts (though the numbers are s3 generated)....the format is exactly the same otherwise.